# Django Integrity Error Not null

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-database

i am learning django and trying to practice by making my own website that will quiz me with questions that i submit in to it. I get this error and i dont know why.

`IntegrityError at /questions/new/
NOT NULL constraint failed: questions_question.date_created`

This is the relevent traceback i believe

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions/new/

Django Version: 1.11
Python Version: 3.5.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'accounts',
 'posts',
 'groups',
 'questions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  328.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: questions_question.date_created) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  217.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/test/questions/views.py" in form_valid
  31.         self.object.save()

File "/Users/chrismaltez/Desktop/pycharmprojects/UDEMY/test/questions/models.py" in save
  33.         super().save(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  806.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  836.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  922.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  961.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1060.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1099.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  80.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/chrismaltez/anaconda3/envs/SimpleSocialEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  328.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /questions/new/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: questions_question.date_created
```

[ScreenShot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8bDK.png)

Here is my relevant code:

```
questions/Views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib import messages

from . import models
from . import forms


# Create your views here.

class QuestionList(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Question


class QuestionDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Question

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()


class CreateQuestion(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Question
    # form = QuestionForm
    fields = ('question', 'answer')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)


class DeleteQuestion(generic.DeleteView):
    model = models.Question
    success_url = reverse_lazy('questions:all')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, "Question Deleted")
        return super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
User = get_user_model()

import misaka

# Create your models here.
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    intro_text = models.TextField(null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)


class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="question", default='')
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
    question = models.TextField(unique=False, default='')
    question_html = models.TextField(default='')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    answer = models.TextField(default='')
    answer_html = models.TextField(unique=False, default='')
    # message = models.TextField(unique=False, default='')
    # message_html = models.TextField(editable=False, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.question_html = misaka.html(self.question)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "questions:single",
            kwargs={
                "username": self.user.username,
                "pk": self.pk
            }
        )

    class Meta:
        # ordering = ["-created_at"]
        unique_together = ["user", "question", "answer", ]



class QuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.TextField(unique=False)
    answer_html = models.TextField()
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just give like this in model Question `date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)` and try.

Comment: post your full traceback

Comment: @Exprator, Full traceback has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you creating a new question in Question model only mentioning two fields. except date_created all remaining fields will be null or default. So the column date_create also change  like this in models :

```
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
```

Because If you are not mentioning null = True constrain default is Not Null. That's  why when you are try to add it shows integrity error.

Comment: Thanks Vikas, ive make your change and it looks like it works. My confusion stems from the fact that I had been following a tutorial, and when i did, it wasnt required to put the auto_now=True, Null = True. it was just left blank as i had it originally. 

How do i know when to add it and when not to add it?

Comment: when you add values to a table to which and all the columns you are passing values except those remaining all columns should be like either default or Null = True.

Comment: okay. thanks! i'll look more into that. As it turned out, i did in fact have to go to most of my models and add the null = True or default fields.